# Laravel view won't display after compiling all my assets through laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

After compiing all my assets through laravel-mix. It displays no error and it went build successful that means all my assets were compiled to the dist/css/ folder.

and I referenced it through

```
  {{ HTML::style('dist/css/auth.css') }}
```

But i get no display from the view. What's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have HTML package installed via Laravel collective
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

If you did already, try to escape `{!! HTML::style('dist/css/auth.css') !!}`

Utimately you could go back to the original

```
<link href="{{ asset("dist/css/auth.css") }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Yes, I already installed it and changed 'Html' to HTML. What should i do after changing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to reference it using relative path:

```
{{ HTML::style('/dist/css/auth.css') }}
```

If this doesn't work, try:

```
<link href="/dist/css/auth.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

By this, you can determine if the problem was in compiling or HTML package.

Comment: I reverted my project without using laravel-mix and instead use the traditional individual asset files. And the view returned, I'm using 5.2 maybe it had issues with laravel-mix